# improve recursion efficiency in python

Tags: python, recursion

```py
def f(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return (1 / (n - 1)) * (f(n - 1) + (1 / f(n - 1)))


n = int(input())
print(str(round(f(n),2)))
```

It's been said that my code is not efficient enough since there are two f(n-1)s in the recursion.
How can I improve it ?

Comment: Save f(n - 1) to a variable?

Comment: Have you any ideas about why having two `f(n-1)` should be less efficient that something else?

Comment: Don't call it twice?

Comment: how can I save f(n-1)to a variable?

Comment: You have to remember that `f` is a function in the programming sense, not a function in the mathematical sense. In mathematics, "f(x) + f(x)" and "2 * f(x)" are exactly equivalent. But in programming, they're not. Calling `f` not only calculates a value for `f(x)`, it also performs computations, which take time and resources; and in some cases it even has explicit side-effects (for instance, calling `print` twice obviously will be different than calling it only once). So, you should avoid calling `f(n-1)` twice. Call it once, save the result, and then use the result twice.

Comment: Part of your code already saves something to a variable. You could just do that again.

Comment: In this case, since `f` is recursive, calling `f(n-1)` twice rather than just once is extremely inefficient, because calculations blow up exponentially. In order to compute `f(n)`, you compute `f(n-1)` twice; then in order to compute `f(n-1)` twice, you compute `f(n-2)` four times; then in order to compute `f(n-2)` four times, you compute `f(n-3)` eight times; etc

Comment: If you have to ask how to save the return value of a function to a variable, you need to spend some time reading [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: I would also look at [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281+%2F+%28n+-+1%29%29+*+%28f%28n+-+1%29+%2B+%281+%2F+f%28n+-+1%29%29%29) when creating more complex equations. It may or may not help simplify your code for you. It kind of doesn't in this case but can in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use python ≥ 3.8 you could use an [assignment expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/):

```
def f(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return (1/(n-1)) * ((F:=f(n-1)) + (1/F)) # (F:=…) gets evaluated as …
                                                 # and instantiates F
     
n = int(input())
print(str(round(f(n),2)))
```

Comment: The downvote wasn't from me, but I'm a bit surprised that you suggested an assignment expression rather than a simple assignment, especially since the OP appears to be new to programming in general and to python in particular.

Comment: @Stef why not? it's part of the new python toolkit, better know what this is, no?

Comment: Because the main difference between the walrus operator and standard assignment is that using the walrus makes code more dense by doing more than one thing at the same time. Although it can be helpful, I think it's the wrong direction to start programming towards. Beginners tend to get confused because they don't separate cleanly the different parts of their code and try to do everything at once. A simple `F = f(n-1)` LINEBREAK `return 1/(n-1) * (F + 1/F)` is, in my opinion, a much better place to start. The walrus is only added complexity on that.

Answer (score -1):

```
def f(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
   
else:
    return (1 / (n - 1)) * (f(n - 1) + (1 / f(n - 1)))

n = int(input())
print(str(round(f(n),2)))
```

#as long as n gets bigger
the function will turn into infinite loop

You can try this:

```
else:
   def alternative(n):
       s= (1 / (n - 1))
        def altr(s):
            return  (n - 1) + (1 / (n - 1))
```